# Check if an attached object have any related data base on navigation property

Tags: c#, .net, linq, reflection, entity-framework-6

I was try to create a function that could detect if one attached object have related data in different table.

I expect to avoid cascade delete but warn the user manually remove the children instead.
It has to be dynamic and each navigation property is also unknown type.
There are too many various class instance, and the properties are changing everyday, so I can't hard code otherwise I can just count them one by one.

My problem is when I selecting the value return by Property.GetValue(), it is boxed object and also there are dynamic type collection within, therefore I can't count the record and do the relevant checking.

My question is how can I cast object convert to ICollection refer to the dynamic type in Linq method?

I was spending one whole day and couldn't get an answer, maybe it is my misunderstanding of the EF concept but please help, many thanks!

```
//Domain Model
public class Course
{
    [Key]
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CourseID")]
    public virtual ICollection<CourseTeacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CourseID")]
    public virtual ICollection<CourseInfo> CourseInfo { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CourseID")]
    public virtual ICollection<CourseSession> Sessions { get; set; }
}

// Controller Delete Action
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    Course course = db.Courses.Find(id);

    bool CannotDel = ValidateRelationalData(typeof(course), course);

    //if failed, warn the user and stop the delete action otherwise delete this record
}

// Public function I was trying to make 
public static bool ValidateRelationalData(Type anyType, dynamic anyInstance)
{
    bool IsExisted = anyType.GetProperties()
        .Where(p => typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType) &&
            p.PropertyType != typeof(byte[]) &&
            p.PropertyType != typeof(string)
        )
        .Select(prop => (ICollection)prop.GetValue(anyInstance, null))
        .Where(c => c.Count() > 0)
        .Any(); //(ICollection)prop.GetValue(anyInstance, null)) won't work here, because no specific type
    return IsExisted;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a base method to iterate the navigation properties of an entity DbSet:

```
private static bool CheckIfAnyNavigationHasData<T>(T o, DbContext context) where T : class
{
    var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
    var elementType = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>().EntitySet.ElementType;
    var navigations = elementType.DeclaredNavigationProperties;

    var collectionNavigations = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(w => w.PropertyType.Name.Equals(typeof(ICollection<>).Name)
                                                                || w.PropertyType.Name.Equals(typeof(HashSet<>).Name)
                                                                || w.PropertyType.Name.Equals(typeof(IList<>).Name))
                                                                .Join(navigations, t => t.Name, n => n.Name, (t, n) => t).ToArray();

    foreach (var property in collectionNavigations)
    {
        var p = o.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name);
        if (p == null)
            continue;

        var propertyValue = p.GetValue(o);
        if (propertyValue == null)
            continue;

        if ((int)property.PropertyType.GetMethod("get_Count").Invoke(propertyValue, null) > 0)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

You need use references below:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
```

So use:

```
using (var ctx = new Context())
{
    var course = ctx.Course.Find(2);
    var cannotDel = CheckIfAnyNavigationHasData(course, ctx);
}
```

Comment: Very advance and the deep of EF understanding, I'd really learn a lot of your code, and you save my day(salute). 
one thing I'm considering is it necessary to constrain the object type must be derived from the Type parameter?
If yes, is there anyway we can do such constraint in the signature?? or we should validate it in the logic? Tested and still studying, will come back when there are more questions, appreciate for your help!

Comment: btw, would you mind telling me about the .GetMethod("get_Count")? how do  you figure out the string"get_Count" since I only know you are invoking the .Count() but how this pattern works?  I guess maybe like "accessor_FnName"??

Comment: Great consideration, I updated the post to change the method signature. About the `.GetMethod("get_Count")` I figured out looking for the reflection method info with `property.PropertyType.GetMethods()`. I dont know why some methods have this pattern, its a good question! salute!